# Blender operator redo fails because of poll

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm writing a Blender addon, and there's a certain Operator that I'm having problems with (let's call it `SquashOperator`).
Now `SquashOperator` can only be applied to objects *once*, in the sense that it
is impossible to squash objects that are already squashed (the precise meaning of *squash* is irrelevant).
In particular, the `SquashOperator` marks the object as *squashed*, and `SquashOperator.poll` returns False if the active object is squashed.

The `SquashOperator` has an option (implemented as an `IntProperty`), and I would like to give the user the possibility of adjusting this option using *operator redo*, the same way that you can adjust the radius of a sphere that was newly inserted. (Let's say that you can squash *horizontally* or *vertically*, and that I want the user to be able to change the squash direction.)

However, once `SquashOperator` is executed, its options can no longer be adjusted, because now `poll` return False. This effectively renders *operator redo* impossible (even though it makes perfect sense for the user to squash something, notice that they squased it horizontally, change their mind, and want to select vertical instead).

> Can *operator redo* be implemented for Operators whose `poll` function returns False for objects that they have already operated on?